# AmCharts how to set horizontal margin between columns?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I would like to ask, how to shrink space between grouped columns in AmChart library?

I tried to find it in documentation but without luck.

Thanks for any help.

See image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space between columns is set by chart.columnSpacing property. But I am not sure if this is the case, could it be you have some graph with missing data?

Comment: chart.columnSpacing property doesn't work for Simple Column chart. I need to minimize space between two Columns. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the column spacing by changing the width(for columns) or height(bars) of the chart div element.